# Is it safe to disable these entries shown in Sysinternals Autoruns?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, autorun, sysinternals

Was directed to this free program http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx through Superuser.

Is it correct that I can un-check the entries which are identified (via Image Path) as, "File not found"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the program set to autorun isn't going to launch because it's not there.

Consider:

- a program, one you aren't the
  engineer of, put them there
- they aren't hurting anything or slowing down your boot time
- if it isn't broken, don't fix it until it is broken

Chances are slim you'd miss the program entries you removed, but if another bit of software installs another module later on, or an update puts the expected file in place, or a mode changes... well you'll have really weird problems nearly nobody else has seen (read: caused).

Answer (score 3):

That's correct as far as I know. It's what I do.